# How to enable warp sync with Aura consensus?

Tags: aura, sync, warp

I have looked at the substrate node template and it shows how to enable Warp sync for Grandpa but I couldn't find an example with Aura.  What do I need to add/modify if it's at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Warp sync protocol](https://spec.polkadot.network/chap-sync#sect-sync-warp) works thanks to the Grandpa protocol. Without Grandpa it is not possible.